# Outlook not indexing

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have a problem with an Outlook Exchange 2010 .ost mailbox. I use this account on seven PC's, and it contains around 11,000 e-mails. It's 9.67GB in size.

Since a couple of months, the indexing function is broken. Outlook doesn't return mail from a certain date, but all the mail before this date are displaying fine.

Of course, I Googled this problem and it came up with several options:

- Rebuild search index

Didn't work. It starts indexing but never ends (after some days all the mail is indexed but nothing is returned when I search)

- Remove Outlook from Windows Search and add it again

Same as previous

- Use SCANPST to repair the .ost

The .ost contained errors and Outlook fixed it, but a second scan says there are still errors.

- Delete profile and add a new one

Same problem

- Reinstalled Windows + Outlook 2010

Same problem

- Installed Lookeen

Same problem, Lookeen can't index. There are a lot of errors

- Use OWA

OWA returns mail within seconds, so instant search works fine online.

- Cached Exchange Mode on/off

I want my mail to be offline so I can work without an internet connection, so this isn't really an option. It worked before so it has to work even in Cached mode.

- Import all mail in MailStore and use the search function in that program

MailStore can find the mail within seconds, but this isn't Outlook so I use it as a workaround

Is there any way to search for corrupt mail which might prevent Windows Search/Lookeen from indexing correctly? I want to use Instant Search because the old-fashioned way is very slow with 11,000 e-mails.

Maybe you guys have some suggestions? I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Anyone with ideas about this subject?

Comment: Update your MS Office to 64-bit, 32-bit office has troubles with mailboxes this big.

Comment: Interesting! I am going to try that on a dev machine :)

Comment: Just saw my own question again. I haven't found a solution yet, installing 64-bit Outlook didn't help. Workaround for now is to use online mode (cached mode off)...